# RegEx for strings containing specific characters and having a specific length

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to write a algorithm to solve letter salads. For example if I have the letters

> ZDFOG

and also know that the word that I am searching for is 3 characters long which words matches if I only can use each character one time?

Lets assume I have a dictionary with the common words.

So the RegXx should match with

> dog
>   Dog
>   Fog
>   fog
>   god
>   God

But should not match with strings like if they are part of the dictionary because every letter should be contained once:

> ffo
>   doo
>   Ggg

So, is there a elegant way to look for all words in a dictionary that contains specific characters and have a specific length?

Comment: it would be good if you posted some input sentence, a search word and the expected matches

Comment: I have updated my question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty unclear.

If your dictionary is common words, why `ffo doo Ggg` are supposed to be present ?

I think it'll be better for you to use a C program to get what you want. Regex is not an algorithm language.

**Anyway this is what you want:** `\b(([A-Za-z])((?!\2)[A-Za-z])((?!\2|\3)[A-Za-z]))\b`

It catches only 3 distinct letters words as you wanted.

Proof: https://regex101.com/r/wAbT99/3

But you need to know that this technique is maybe slow.

Comment: lets assume that these words are inside the dictionary.

Comment: Would a clever for loop be faster than a RegEx in this case?

Comment: Depends how your dictionary is implemented. One word per line, one line with every words separated with a space, which language, perl, c, python, ruby. You can try with this regex and if you think it's too slow, do it using your own program.

Answer (score 0):

Without considering duplicated letters, eg `egg`, the solution is simple; use an anchored look ahead for each letter:

```
^(?=.*F)(?=.*O)(?=.*G).*
```

With duplicates, it a little uglier:

```
^(?=.*E)(?=.*G.*G).*
```

You could use the general solution of:

```
^(?=(.*E){1})(?=(.*G){2}).*
```

Where the number of the repetition `{n}` is the number of occurrences of the letter is the target word.360

Comment: So I have to create all the combinations to look for because at the start there are more letters given than in the solutions? Like the letter Z in my example.

Comment: @king no. The order of the look aheads is irrelevant. You need to create one look ahead with the correct quantity for each distinct letter. For example, to search for "EGG", the regexes `^(?=(.*G){2})(?=.*E).*` and `^(?=.*E)(?=(.*G){2}).*` are both correct

Comment: yes but lets assume in your egg example the letters LTGEGU are given and the word length must be 3 letters. so I have to create all the combinations that can be made with the letters LTGEGU and length 3 to get match for all the words in the dictionary or not?

Comment: @king I just realised you want to match *any* word, not a specific word. You can still do it by using an *alternation* (ie an "OR"). Eg, to match "EGG", "LEG" or "GUT" use `^((?=.*E)(?=(.*G){2}).*|(?=.*L)(?=.*E)(?=.*G)|(?.*G)(?=.*U)(?=.*T)).*`. Word length is not relevant - you could have a variety. Also, regex is not the right way to go for this task. It *could* be done, but that doesn't mean it *should* be done.